why is pyGithub add_membership throwing an AssertionError?
I am using PyGithub version 2.3.0 and would like to add a team member to a team.
Using the github enterprise server web application I confirm the user I am trying to add is a organization member and I could add the user via the web application.
Trying to achieve the same programatically does not work and the last step when calling team.add_membership(user) fails with an AssertionError returning just the user passed in the AssertionError exception.
Previous steps all were successful: i.e. using token based authentication I can connect to github enterprise server, get the organization and the team fine and can also list all users in the team. The token was generated as classic token with admin:org, repo scope.
from github import Github
from github.GithubException import GithubException
g = GitHub(base_url='https://.../api/V3', login_or_token=xy)
org = g.get_organization('xy')
team = org.get_team_by_slug("my_team")
try:
    team.add_membership(user) // user is of data type str and a valid account and org member
except GithubException as ge: // not thrown
except AssertionError as ae: // thrown
    logging.error(ae)
    traceback.print_exc()
except Exception as e:

Log messages:
2024-08-16 21:06:55,152 | urllib3.connectionpool | DEBUG | https://github.XXXXXX.de:443 "GET /api/v3/orgs/dev HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2024-08-16 21:06:55,155 | root | INFO | connection to github established
2024-08-16 21:06:55,155 | root | INFO | add new team members to team
2024-08-16 21:06:55,203 | urllib3.connectionpool | DEBUG | https://github.XXXXXX.de:443 "GET /api/v3/orgs/dev/teams/YYYYY_Readers HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2024-08-16 21:06:55,204 | root | DEBUG | team found: Team(name="YYYYY_Readers", id=1827)
2024-08-16 21:06:55,205 | root | ERROR | user acct123 could not be added to team YYYYY_Readers - terminating
2024-08-16 21:06:55,205 | root | ERROR | AssertionError: acct123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxx/git/repo/python/ghAdd_TeamMembers.py", line 119, in <module>
    team.add_membership(user)
  File "/home/xxxxx/git/repo/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/github/Team.py", line 196, in add_membership
    assert isinstance(member, github.NamedUser.NamedUser), member
AssertionError: acct123

I tried team.invite and team.add_to_members both returning 'Team' object has no attribute 'invite', respectively 'add_to_members'.

Add traceback.print_exc() to the except clause to get the full traceback (and show it here as properly formatted text in the question).
